# I'm trying to invoke a pig script using python. But its returning exit status 1

Tags: apache-pig

```
#PIG script execution
hadoop_channel_obj = hadoop_transport_obj.open_session()
command = 'cd ' + pig_path
LOG.do_log('INFO', 'command is ' + command)
#hadoop_channel_obj.exec_command(command)
command = '/usr/local/pig/bin/pig ' + 'DL_Base.pig'
#sys.path.append('.')
#time.sleep(1)
LOG.do_log('DEBUG', 'Executing ' + pig_filename)
LOG.do_log('INFO', 'command is ' + command)
#hadoop_channel_obj = hadoop_transport_obj.open_session()
hadoop_channel_obj.exec_command(command)
exit_status = hadoop_channel_obj.recv_exit_status()
LOG.do_log('INFO', exit_status)
```

The log shows as below

```
2014-05-13 01:58:37,161 DEBUG : Archiving DL_DLY_PRE_CUST_MASTER_20140512.csv.gz
2014-05-13 01:58:38,008 INFO : command is cd /home/hadoop/scripts/Base
2014-05-13 01:58:38,008 DEBUG : Executing DL_Base.pig
2014-05-13 01:58:38,008 INFO : command is /usr/local/pig/bin/pig DL_Base.pig
2014-05-13 01:58:38,022 INFO : 1
2014-05-13 01:58:38,022 WARNING : Pig execution failed
2014-05-13 01:58:38,122 INFO : transport_obj closed
```

Comment: I'm trying to invoke a "PIG" script using python. But its returning exit status 1

Comment: I'm not sure this error has to do with Python; I would check apache-pig's logs.

Comment: Ofcourse.. I have also tried the same but there is no pig log... :(      I have also added few more commands before invoking pig to check if the script is working.... and it was fine but invoking pig is causing the problem...

Comment: I am going to remove the python tag because the problem seems to be with pig and not Python.

Comment: I have tried numerous ways and i'm having this issue only when python script is invoking pig. I have included my pig command in an shell script and invoked the shell script in python. My shell script is working fine but when invoked by python, pig is failing with exit status 1.....

Comment: Pass the full path to `DL_Base.pig`

Comment: we have tried this too.. but it failed